# getAnnotation(Class) return always null while processing annotations

Tags: java, annotation-processing

I'm trying to process annotations, my processor class extends `AbstractProcessor` and the `process` method is like the following :

**KeyAnnotationProcessor.java**

```
    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
            RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {

        // Instanciation du Visitor
        final KeyVisitor visitor = new KeyVisitor(processingEnv);

        // On boucle sur toutes les Annotations :
        for (final TypeElement  declaration : annotations) {

            // On "visite" chacune des déclarations trouvées :
            declaration.accept(visitor,roundEnv);
        }

   }
```

As it's shown on the provided code, I'm using an Visitor for each annotation, the code of Visitor :

**KeyVisitor.java**

```
public class KeyVisitor extends SimpleElementVisitor6<Void, RoundEnvironment> {

    final ProcessingEnvironment env;

    public KeyVisitor(final ProcessingEnvironment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    @Override
    public Void visitType(TypeElement e, RoundEnvironment p) { 
        Key cle=e.getAnnotation(Key.class);
        if(cle!=null){
            processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE , "OK");
        }else{
            processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR , "ERROR");
        }
    }
```

This is my Key class

**Key.java**

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Key {
    String description();
    String filename();
}
```

And this is the exemple I try to process, it's a java file :

**OracleDirectory.java**

```
@Key(description = "Oracle Directory configuration", filename = "oracle-directory")
public enum OracleDirectoryProperties {

}
```

The problem is that `cle` is always null in `visitType` of `Keyvisitor`, why is the `getAnnotation` method always returning null ? any help would be apreciated.

Comment: "This is my Key class" That's your `OracleDirectoryProperties` class.

Comment: Sorry I've just corrected my post.

Comment: Do you have the `SupportedAnnotationTypes` annotation on your processor class?

Comment: yes well the code in my visitor get's executed which means that he recognize my processor's options.

Comment: how/when are you activating your processing? have you confirmed with other retentionpolicy options that it isn't about that?

Comment: I tried Runtime but i still get the same results, I'm activating at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure this is your problem:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
```

Change it to

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
```

The SOURCE retention policy tells Java, "this annotation only needs to appear in the source" -- therefore when `javac` parses the code, it throws that annotation away. You want it available in the annotation processor, and therefore need to tell `javac` to retain the information in the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

The set that is passed in to `process` represents the types of annotations that the processor is being asked to process. In your case, it would contain a `TypeElement` for `@interface Key`. As `Key` is not annotated with `@Key`, calling `getAnnotation(Key.class)` on it will return `null`.

To get the elements *annotated with* `@Key`, you need to call `roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Key.class)`. That will return a set containing the `TypeElement` for `enum OracleDirectoryProperties`, which your visitor will then process as you expected, retrieving the `@Key` annotation on it.